# React: Conditional rendering of functional components using state | is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Hi so i am trying to conditionally render one of three aspects of a one page game and i am stuck at one of the first hurdles.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState("Intro");


  if (currentPage === "Intro") {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Intro setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (currentPage === "GameContainer") {
    return (
      <div>
        <GameContainer  setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (currentPage === "EndGame") {
    return (
      <div>
        <EndGame  setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This renders the  component fine but there is a button which i have hooked up to an on click function in the intro component which i am hoping would change the state and hence the render.

```js
import React from "react";

function Intro(setCurrentPage) {
  function startGame() {
     setCurrentPage("GameContainer");
  }

  return (
    <div className="intro">

      <div class="hoverButton">
        <button class="startButton" onClick={startGame} alt="start game">
          Start Game!
        </button>
      </div>
      <p id="footNote">written using react.js</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

I get the error "setCurrentPage is not a function".

I know the resources are out there but i just can't figure out how to achieve what I am aiming for or understand where I am going wrong?

Any advice appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring the prop `setCurrentPage` incorrectly in `Intro`. You should add curly braces when destructuring the prop directly, in your case, `{setCurrentPage}`.

Try updating it as :

```
import React from "react";

function Intro({setCurrentPage}) {
  function startGame() {
     setCurrentPage("GameContainer");
  }

  return (
    <div className="intro">

      <div class="hoverButton">
        <button class="startButton" onClick={startGame} alt="start game">
          Start Game!
        </button>
      </div>
      <p id="footNote">written using react.js</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it! I'm going to go read about destructuring, do you recommend any good sites/articles that are more functional than class based?

Comment: @newbywebber Glad it helped. For functional components, I would recommend reading [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component/)